# How to integrate RabbitMQ RPC into FastApi properly

Tags: python, rabbitmq, fastapi, rpc

I am improving my FastAPI project. One of the methods needs to run a heavy computational task on another machine. Due to the high load this should be done in a queue way. I am following [RabbitMQ RPC guide](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html) to perform remote procedure call via message queue.

This guide suggests to create exclusive queue for each client-server session, which means if I will create new instance for each method call then for N calls there will be N queues created, which is obviously inefficient.

So, my questions are:

1. Is there a way in FastAPI to create fixed pull of workers and give each worker only one unique instance of RPCClient? Or, maybe, create a fixed pull from those clients and give each new worker one client from this pull?
2. How badly will be the slow if I use strait-forward solution mentioned above?
3. Is there efficient way to return back results for **several workers** via **single response queue**?

Comment: For this purpose, I would suggest looking into [Celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html). It automates a lot of your questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve all those problems by simply using [Celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/) with RabbitMQ as backend